# UK visa refusal because of large transactions in bank statement

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

How to clarify this case for reapplying?
The transactions which are being mentioned were done my husband's mother in their joint account which was just because my mother in law who already have a visit visa of UK for 10 years was also travelling to UK and we all intended to spend few days together with family. So, she transferred this amount from her personal account to this joint account so that we all could collectively use it for our trip.

How to clarify this to ECO so that we don't get refusal again. is it better that this time my husband apply visa for just his self rather than applying for whole family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new application should state that your mother-in-law is funding some (or all?) of the costs, explain why she’s doing that, and provide her bank statement to show where the deposit came from. Use the section at the end of the application to explain the background to the transfer of funds that led to the refusal. If your mother-in-law is travelling with you, include that in the application too. The first refusal will also need to be declared. From your first question [Reapplying for UK Visit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116283/reapplying-for-uk-visit-visa) it appears that your entire family will be travelling; this could be a red flag unless both you and your husband can prove strong ties to home.

Comment: Thank you for your response. in previous application we havent mentioned that mother-in-law will fund for our trip. if we add this new statement then wont they say that you are not financially stable?

Comment: @Marium The ECO will tie up the first and any subsequent applications. You need to determine the basis on which you are applying, and tell the whole truth about it. The first refusal was for funds parking, they already know about it so you need to explain it, even if you have sufficient resources to qualify for a visa without your mother-in-law’s assistance. IMHO you have already complicated the situation by a less than transparent first application, if you apply again you need to keep it simple and prove and explain every point.